# Get the open graph image for a webpage? (The way facebook embeds a thumbnail image when you share its link)

Tags: javascript, html, image, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

On my webpage I want to share a link - let's say to [this wikipedia page for Superhero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superhero)

In the code for that page there is the following code in the head tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d6/Connecticut_ComiCONN_Superhero_Mascot..jpg/640px-Connecticut_ComiCONN_Superhero_Mascot..jpg">
```

This is the thumbnail for that page that is shown if you share the link on social media. (Most pages now have one).

Is there a way to retrieve that image url to embed on my normal webpage page?

I'm using CSS, HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use https://www.opengraph.io/, for example:

1. Make request to https://opengraph.io/api/1.1/site/https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSuperhero?app_id=f6ef4e6b-4162-40d7-8404-b80736d4bd55 (`https://opengraph.io/api/1.1/site/${url_encoded_link}?app_id=${your_api_key}`
2. Get image URL from the JSON response, which looks like this:

```
{
   //...
   "openGraph":{
      "title":"Superhero - Wikipedia",
      "type":"website",
      "image":{
         "url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Connecticut_ComiCONN_Superhero_Mascot..jpg",
         "width":"1200",
         "height":"1005"
      }
   },
   //...
}
```

Note, that the free tier only allows 100 requests per month. And I'm not affiliated with it.

Alternatively, you can use something like [open-graph-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph-scraper) - never tried, but looks promising, will require running NodeJS server as far as I understand.

This one [parse-open-graph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-open-graph) can work in browser, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately that seems prohibitive for me but I accept it as the answer thank you